# Why are angular2 Lifecycle Hooks not working after using jquery query builder?

Tags: jquery, angular, query-builder

I imported jquery query builder in my project as [How to use Jquery Query Builder in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820788/how-to-use-jquery-query-builder-in-angular) told.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.templateService.getTags(this.contentType)
  .then(tags => {
    this.tags = tags;
  });
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.getQueryBuilder();
}

getQueryBuilder() {
let self = this;
if (self.builder) {
  $(self.builder.nativeElement).queryBuilder({
      plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors','not-group'],

      filters: [{
          id: 'tag',
          label: 'Tag',
          type: 'string',
          input: 'select',
          values: {
                1: 'Books',
                2: 'Movies',
                3: 'Music',
                4: 'Tools',
                5: 'Goodies',
                6: 'Clothes'
            },
          operators: ['equal']
      }],

      rules: this.rules_basic
  });

}
}
```

Although it worked, angular lifecycle hooks are not working.
It always comes to the getQueryBuilder() function first,usually ngOnInit() executes first,and then gAfterViewInit(),and the autocompletion is not working.Why? Can somebody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you informed the class that it will be implementing ``AfterViewInit`` ?

Comment: Informed the class? I don't quite understand that.I need to use a variable in getQueryBuilder() which came from a service when ngOnInit() executed,but it came directly to the getQueryBuilder() function and then executed ngOnInit() when I debuged it. I don't know why.

Comment: ``ngOnInit()`` will get executed and later ``ngAfterViewInit()`` will get executed . ``ngOnInit()`` won't wait for service response as it is async. So to use the variable inside your ``getQueryBuilder() `` , you'll have to call ``getQueryBuilder() `` after getting the response

Comment: I tried that,but it's still not working.This is kind of weird.I also tried to put 
both `getQueryBuilder()` and the variable into `ngOnInit()`,it still came to `getQueryBuilder()` first, and then the variable from service.

Comment: can you post how you've subscribed to service in ngOnInit() ?

Comment: Just like the code above,it gets the tags variable from the templateService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
ngOnInit(){
this.templateService.getTags(this.contentType)
  .then(tags => {
    this.tags = tags;
    this.getQueryBuilder();
  });
}
```

Now only after the response from templateService , `this.getQueryBuilder()` is executed