# How to remove Property 'queryBuilder' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-query-builder

How to remove

> Property 'queryBuilder' does not exist on type 'JQuery < HTMLElement>'

on integration of Jquery query builder in Angular.

**angular.json:**

```
"scripts": [
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
"node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js",
...]
```

**app.componenet.ts**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.js';
import 'jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.js';

...


private getQueryBuilder() {
$('#builder').queryBuilder({
    //plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
    filters: [{
        id: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        id: 'category',
        label: 'Category',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'select',
        values: {
            1: 'Books',
            2: 'Movies',
            3: 'Music',
            4: 'Tools',
            5: 'Goodies',
            6: 'Clothes'
        },
        operators: ['equal', 'not_equal', 'in', 'not_in', 'is_null', 'is_not_null']
    }, {
        id: 'in_stock',
        label: 'In stock',
        type: 'integer',
        input: 'radio',
        values: {
            1: 'Yes',
            0: 'No'
        },
        operators: ['equal']
    }],
    rules: this.rules_basic
});
```

}

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getQueryBuilder();
}
```

I did things in this ([How to use Jquery Query Builder in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820788/how-to-use-jquery-query-builder-in-angular)) thread but It throws error and leads failed compilation. Sometimes application is running with this error also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one,  it will work.

```
import 'jquery';
import 'jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.min.js';
import 'jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js';

declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

The path to your queryBuilder plugin is either wrong

```
node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js
```

or you have not NPM installed it.

Comment: Hi, I'm sure, I installed jQuery-QueryBuilder and used correct path only.

Comment: That error message is stating that the queryBuilder plugin has not been added to the jQuery object.

Comment: Ok Adrian. How to add queryBuilder to the jQuery object.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure node_modules/jQuery-QueryBuilder/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js exists and try putting a console.log at the top of the file to make sure it is getting executed.

Comment: I checked query-builder.standalone.min.js is there. and it is executed. Still getting error. Thanks.